# Failed to download repository information (Software Updater)

Tags: update-manager, repository

When I'm trying to update my system (Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) through `Software Updater`, I receive the following error message:

```
Failed to download repository information

Check your Internet connection.
```

First I thought it might be the server where it's trying to download the repositories, so I went to `Software Updater -> Settings -> Ubuntu Software` and changed the `Download from` selection from `Server for United States` to `Other -> Select Best Server`. As a result, my new server is http://www.nic.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/archive.ubuntu.com

When returning to the main window, I receive a following notification:

```
The information about available software is out-of-date

To install software and updates from newly added or changed sources,
you have to reload the information about available software. 

You need a working Internet connection to continue.
```

Now, after clicking the button `Reload`, Software Updater starts to update the cache. However, this results into a failure with the following error message:

```
Failed to download repository information

Check your Internet connection.

Details

W:Target Packages (Packages) is configured multiple times in
/etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54, W:Target
Translations (en) is configured multiple times in
/etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54, W:The 
repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/landronimirc/clamtk/ubuntu xenial 
Release' does not have a Release file., W:Data from such a repository 
can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use., 
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user 
configuration details., E:Failed to fetch
http://ppa.launchpad.net/landronimirc/clamtk/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/bina
ry-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found, E:Some index files failed to 
download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

So, it seems I am unable to update my system at the moment. Does any of the good people here on the forum know how to fix the problem?

Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: Duplicate [How do I restore the default repositories](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is very simple.

First, you have two problems.

The errors:

W:Target Packages (Packages) is configured multiple times in
/etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54

W:Target Translations (en) is configured multiple times in
/etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54,

are because you have some duplicated information in the file /etc/apt/sources.list. In terminal, type `cd /etc/apt`, then `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`. Review lines 53 and 54, and remove the duplication and save the file.

The error:

W:The repository http://ppa.launchpad.net/landronimirc/clamtk/ubuntu xenial

is because you've got the wrong Ubuntu version for this particular PPA. Change xenial to saucy. The incorrect entry will either be in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`, or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/landronimirc-clamtk-quantal.list` (quantal may be something else).

Ask if you need more help. Cheers, Al

Comment: Thanks. I already ran the commands suggested by @sagarbhooshan below, and I couldn't find the lines 53 and 54 in `/etc/apt/sources.list`anymore. Actually, the file seems to have only 16 lines right now (main repos, 1 line;  update repos, 4 lines; partner repo, 1 line). On the other hand, running `sudo apt-get update`results in **five** altered error lines: (1) `W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/landronimirc/clamtk/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.`, (2) `N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.`,

Comment: (3) `N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.`, (4) `N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.`, and (5) `N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.` When it comes to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` (wow, I just learned how to use the `ls` command), the appropriate files I've got seem to be `landronimirc-ubuntu-clamtk-xenial.list` and/or `landronimirc-ubuntu-clamtk-xenial.list.save` Should I rename the file (replace xenial with saucy), or alter the file's contents? :-O

Comment: You edit the file's content, changing xenial to saucy. In terminal, type **sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/landronimirc-ubuntu-clamtk-xenial.list**. Cheers, Al

Comment: Thousand thanks! That made the trick :-) `Software Updater` working again!

Answer (score -1):

Well I recommend to follow the steps below in your terminal.

1. Become privileged user.

   ```
   sudo -i
   ```
2. Take a backup of your current source list.

   ```
   mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.backup
   ```
3. Clean your system package cache.

   ```
   sudo apt-get clean; apt-get autoclean
   ```
4. Add new source list Igenerated for you with United States mirror.

   ```
   curl https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/txt/xenial/sources_e3432824238c837b112c3056e4e4e4c5e16313a2.txt | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
5. Add the GPG key.

   ```
   curl https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/txt/xenial/gpg_e3432824238c837b112c3056e4e4e4c5e16313a2.txt | sudo tee /etc/apt/gpg_keys.txt
   ```
6. Now update.

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

That's it. Now try your Software Center / Updater.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I followed your instructions, but `Software Updater` still gives me the error message:

    `Failed to download repository information
    
    Check your internet connection.`

Meanwhile, here is the end part of terminal after running the commands:

    `Fetched 39,1 MB in 34s (1 121 kB/s) 
    Reading package lists... Done
    W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/landronimirc/clamtk/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
    N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.`

Comment: `N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
    E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/landronimirc/clamtk/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
    E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
    root@XXXX:~#`

I hope this helps...

Comment: Ok. That may be cache problem. execute the following : rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*     ; sudo apt-get update

Comment: I ran the rm -command, and the terminal gives me the following: `XXXX@XXXX:~$ rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*
rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/apt/lists/partial': Is a directory`. Any idea how to proceed? :-O Thanks a lot for your help, by the way...!

Comment: Completely unnecessary. AND, in steps 4/5, I personally wouldn't get those files from a site in china. Cheers, Al

Comment: rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*    should be run it as root. so first try this command sudo -i  then the former command.